# How to transpose a dataframe depending on variables in R?

Tags: r, transpose

I have a dataframe like this: (data)

```
Country IndicatorName 1960 1965
France Air 2 3
France Elec 9 10 
France Mobile 2 4 
Germany Air 50 43
Germany Elec 43 23
Germany Mobile 45 66
USA Air 87 2
USA Elec 19 81
USA Mobile 1 77
```

I would like to have this data in order to plot it: (data_new)

```
Years  Country Air Elect Mobile
1960 France 2 9 2
1960 Germany 50 43 45
1960 USA 87 19 1
1965 France 3 10 4
1965 Germany 43 23 66
1965 USA 2 81 77
```

I kind want to transpose (data) in order to have (data_new).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape to the expected format using either `gather/spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
      gather(Years, Val, 3:4) %>% 
      spread(IndicatorName, Val)
#   Country Years Air Elec Mobile
#1  France  1960   2    9      2
#2  France  1965   3   10      4
#3 Germany  1960  50   43     45
#4 Germany  1965  43   23     66
#5     USA  1960  87   19      1
#6     USA  1965   2   81     77
```

---

Or use `recast` from `library(reshape2)`.  The function is a wrapper for `melt/dcast` where `melt` does the same thing as `gather` from `tidyr` i.e. converting 'wide' to 'long' format, and `dcast` converts the 'long' back to 'wide' (as `spread` from `tidyr`).  In the `dcast` formula, we can use the full formula by indicating `Country + variable ~ IndicatorName` or we can use `...` to specify all the remaining variables on the lhs of `~`.

```
 library(reshape2)
 recast(df1, measure.var=c('1960', '1965'), ...~IndicatorName, value.var='value')
# Country variable Air Elec Mobile
#1  France     1960   2    9      2
#2  France     1965   3   10      4
#3 Germany     1960  50   43     45
#4 Germany     1965  43   23     66
#5     USA     1960  87   19      1
#6     USA     1965   2   81     77
```

Just to understand this better,

```
 melt(df1, measure.vars=c('1960', '1965')) %>% 
            dcast(., Country+variable~IndicatorName, value.var='value')
```

Also, note that we can change the variable name in the `melt` step,

```
 melt(df1, measure.vars=c('1960', '1965'), variable.name='Years') %>%
           dcast(., Country+Years ~IndicatorName, value.var='value')
```

The `%>%` is from `dplyr`.  (It is not needed.  We could have done this in two steps).

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("France", "France", "France", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "USA", "USA", "USA"), IndicatorName = c("Air", 
"Elec", "Mobile", "Air", "Elec", "Mobile", "Air", "Elec", "Mobile"
), `1960` = c(2L, 9L, 2L, 50L, 43L, 45L, 87L, 19L, 1L), `1965` = c(3L, 
10L, 4L, 43L, 23L, 66L, 2L, 81L, 77L)), .Names = c("Country", 
"IndicatorName", "1960", "1965"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Upvoted, but if you allow me I would have preferred a small explanation of the syntax used (I'm unsure `...~IndicatorName` is intuitive for all future readers)

Comment: @akrun thank you. It works! I used df1 %>% gather(Years, Val, 3:4) %>% spread(IndicatorName, Val).